# Convert text blob to sentences

Tags: python, nltk

Can nltk be used to convert a blob of text to sentences.

For example:

```
sen = 'this is a test sentence1 this is a test sentence 2 this is a test'
tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(sen)

len(tokens)
```

returns 1, but I expect the list to be of length 3 for three sentences:

```
Sentence 1 : this is a test sentence1 
Sentence 2 : this is a test sentence 2 
Sentence 3 : this is a test
```

Comment: Sentences are not separated by the `sentence` word in English but by `.`, `?`, `!`...

Answer (score 0):

You can't recognize sentences with nltk alone due to `TextBlob` recognizing sentences based off of punctuation.  You should take a look at [this](https://praneethbedapudi.medium.com/deepcorrection2-automatic-punctuation-restoration-ac4a837d92d9). It uses machine learning to try to recognizes where the end of sentences are and automatically fills in punctation.

From there you could insert your output into `TextBlob` and it will split the paragraph.